# SharePoint 2019 Search is broken after configuring SSL

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

We have implemented SSL and redirecting http to https based on below scenario.

1. Default Zone URL: http://servername:10101, we extended this to intranet zone with https://servername.projects.com:10105 and updated the bindings in IIS. Sites are working fine with SSL URL.
2. in IIS for http://servername:10101 we have created URL redirect to https://servername.projects.com:10105 so that users will be redirected to SSL URL for old links. Redirects are working perfect.

When we are trying to search anything in https://servername.projects.com:10105 is not showing any result and no error in ULS. We have tried enabling NO SSL Warning in search service application and also tried with SSL Urls in contents source but no luck. We have restarted all search related services but no luck. We can see crawled contents from SSL URL in Crawl Log- URL.

Comment: Have you added all certificates of the certificate-chain to TrustedSites? Are there any errors in the crawl-log?

Comment: We have added all the certificates to certificates chain to trusted sites and there is no error in crawl log.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the CrawlLog? I.e. which urls are being crawled. As Trevor & Kally said: It is vital, that the Default Zone is crawled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the AAM on the Default Zone as that is what SharePoint needs to crawl; or keep the AAM you have for the DZ and direct users to the new URL without the IIS redirect in place.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I have updated default zone url to  https://servername.projects.com:10105 and intranet zone url to http://servername:10101 and also tried to run full crawl again but still search is not working.

Answer (score 0):

How did you set the content source? You need to make sure you are using the default zone url.

An article about [Problems Crawling the non-Default zone *Explained](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sharepoint_strategery/problems-crawling-the-non-default-zone-explained) for your reference, hope it helps you.

Comment: Default zone url: https://servername.projects.com:10105 content source also have the same url for crawling.